# Play .ts (media file) in chrome with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, m3u, transport-stream

I want to play a .ts (transport stream, not TypeScript) file in chrome.

Could someone please help me?

Comment: Convert it to one of these supported formats: https://www.chromium.org/audio-video/

Comment: Is this library good for you? https://github.com/xqq/mpegts.js